# How can I change current URL with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, url

I have a select tag to choose the number of 'rows' to display on the current table.

```
<%=select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10,20,50,100]....some more code...., onchange => "if (this.value) {windows.location='?per_page='+(this.value);}' %>
```

And this works fine. However I also have a search function which changes the url of the current page i.e

```
www.url.com/blahblah&search="input"
```

How can I insert a string after, say, the first 'blah', with an onchange event? 
Because if I change the number of rows displayed after doing a search, it completely disregards the search parameters and shows every result again..

Comment: Have you tried `location.href` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was very unclear at first what you were meaning by your question, but I think I understand. You have two params you want to pass into the url upon changing that drop-down selection. This means that you have to retrieve the search value of the current URL. You can do this in a couple of ways.

For one, you can include a hidden input somewhere in your page that includes the value of the search parameter, e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" value="[the search param value]" id="search_value"/>
```

then access the value by using

```
document.getElementById("search_value").value;
```

You just append that appropriately to the url you are building.

Another way is to access the `location.search` attribute then parse the url for the value you need using RegExp or string manipulation methods in javascript. e.g.

```
var urlSearchParams = location.search.replace('?','').split('&');
var valueMap = {};
searchParams.forEach(function(a){
    var kv = a.split('=');
    valueMap[kv[0]] = kv[1];
});
//get the search value you want
var search = valueMap["search"];
```

A third way is to retrieve the param and add it into the JS code template you are making using the rails template system.

Comment: I actually already solved this issue about 3 minutes after posting it but yes it is along these lines, although some of the code you have at the end is unnecessary :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //jquery
    $(location).attr('href');

 //pure javascript
 var pathname = window.location.pathname;
 
 // to show it in an alert window
    alert(window.location);
});
```